# Register an extender provider for all project types

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, vsix, vs-extensibility

I have a Visual Studio extension that adds an property to the property grid of a project item. It is done by registering an extender provider like this:

```
    void RegisterExtenderProvider()
    {
        var provider = new PropertyExtenderProvider(_dte, this);
        string name = PropertyExtenderProvider.ExtenderName;
        RegisterExtenderProvider(VSConstants.CATID.CSharpFileProperties_string, name, provider);
        RegisterExtenderProvider(VSConstants.CATID.VBFileProperties_string, name, provider);
    }

    void RegisterExtenderProvider(string extenderCatId, string name, IExtenderProvider extenderProvider)
    {
        int cookie = _dte.ObjectExtenders.RegisterExtenderProvider(extenderCatId, name, extenderProvider);
        _registerExtenderProviders.Add(cookie, extenderProvider);
    }
```

It works fine for C# and VB projects, but only for those...

- **Is it possible to make it work for all project types?**
- **If not, where can I find the CATIDs of other project types?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to register the extender provider for all project types.

- Project types may or may not be backed by MSBuild.
- Project types may or may not have a project file (Web Site projects do not have a project file).
- Project types may or may not produce executable output. An example of the wide variety of project types, you have [*.wixproj](http://wixtoolset.org/), [*.ucproj](http://pixelminegames.com/nfringe/), [*.javaproj](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bc561769-36ff-4a40-9504-e266e8706f93), [*.shfbproj](https://shfb.codeplex.com/), and many more.

Rather, you need to register your extender provider for the project systems you know it supports.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Ideally I'd like to support any project type that has an MSBuild-compatible project file, but if it's not possible I'll settle for a closed set of project types. The trouble is that I can't find the list of known project CATIDs anywhere. Do you have any idea where I could find that?

Comment: Thanks, but project type GUIDs are not the same as CATIDs... Actually, I know the CATIDs I have to use for C# and VB projects, but I can't find them anywhere in the registry, so they must be defined somewhere else.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque You are correct. Sorry about that! The CATIDs only really exist in code such as [this example](https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/SHFB/blob/fb5d842ccd9f1320272c7d14fe24d8a9a6f2924f/SHFB/Source/SandcastleBuilderPackage/Nodes/SandcastleBuilderProjectNode.cs#L172-L192).